# Check for non-occuring events in siddhiQL

Tags: siddhi

I have a use case where i need to check that after a particular event A has occurred, does it re-occur in the next 20 mins. I cannot use windowing because we are receiving lots of events every second and siddhiQL may run out of memory eventually as windowing will store events in-memory. Is there some other better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use siddhi [pattern](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#pattern) for Detecting event non-occurrence.

```
from e1=TestStream -> not TestStream[e1.roomNo == roomNo and temp <= e1.tempSet] for '20 min'
select e1.roomNo as roomNo
insert into AlertStream;
```